# Many to many relationship with itself

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema, relationships

I need some help with my database relations. My problem is that I don't know if i'm approaching this problem the right way. I have an application where users can befriend other users similar to friendships on Facebook.

```
╔═══════════╗
║   Users   ║
╠═══════════╣
║ #id       ║ 
║ *username ║
║ *password ║
╚═══════════╝

╔══════════════╗
║ User_friends ║
╠══════════════╣
║ *user_id     ║
║ *friend_id   ║
╚══════════════╝    

╔════════════════╗
║ Friend_request ║
╠════════════════╣
║ #id            ║
║ *user_id       ║
║ *friend_id     ║
║ *created_at    ║
║ *updated_at    ║
╚════════════════╝
```

User **John Doe** wants to login to my application and send a friendship request to **Jane Doe** so a record will be stored in `Friend_request` and when **Jane Doe** logs in to the application she will see a notice that someone wants a friendship. When **Jane Doe** accepts **John Doe's** friendship request I want to store two records into `User_friends` because **John Doe** is a friend of **Jane Doe** and **Jane Doe** has a friendship with **John Doe**

I am not sure if i'm approaching this problem in the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have done is reasonable and straightforward.

PS There are further candidate keys (`UNIQUE NOT NULL` column sets not containing smaller ones) than the `PRIMARY KEY`s that you have indicated (via #):

```
Users (username) -- likely -- though not on Stack Overflow
User_friends (user_id, friend_id)
Friend_request (user_id, friend_Id)
```

PPS Re title "Many to many relationship with itself": I guess you mean that in `User_friends` and in `Friend_request` entity class Users has a "many to many relationship with itself". Tables represent (application) relationships. Values in rows are thus related, and entities they designate are thus related. There are the FOREIGN KEYs from the `user_id` and `friend_id` columns to `Users id`. These are often *called* "relationships" although they are facts/constraints. (If you queried for the user names of a user and requested or accepted friend then you would `JOIN` `Users` with itself.)